# Getting errors when trying to send something using Gmail and Mail 5

Tags: email, security, gmail, keychain, certificate

I've had a problem for awhile with a Gmail account linked to Mail, which arose last summer after I upgraded to Lion. When I try to send a signed message (signed, in terms of security, not a signature at the end of a message), a small error message pops up for no more than half a second (way to short for me to read), but I've been able to make out the message based on a well-timed screen capture:

> An error occured while trying to sign this message with a certificate from [myusername]@gmail.com. Verify that your certificate for this address is correct, and that its private key is in your keychain.

I have no idea what to do in this case, as my knowledge of digital security is superficial, to say the least. I posted this question on Apple Community Discussions awhile ago, but I got no answers whatsoever. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

It took me a minute to find what he was talking about but near the right corner of the message toolbar you will see an icon that looks like a burst with a checkmark. Click this and it will turn to a burst with an x. Here is a screen shot.
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/qeJSO.png]

Comment: ugh, thank you.  what a banal and unclear feature / bug!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little tick that adds the security certificate by default. Just click it to turn if off and it's solved. You can't miss it.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to explain which "tick" you are refering to here?

Answer (score 0):

The Digital Signature "selection" is now located in the subject box to the far right ... uncheck to not have the request come up for your user name and password